# can't login to Unity always login to Unity 2D

Tags: unity, nvidia, unity-2d, x11

I select Ubuntu on login and it always loads Unity 2D.

I ran

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

And got this error

```
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  137 (NV-GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  4 ()
  Resource id in failed request:  0x21f
  Serial number of failed request:  42
  Current serial number in output stream:  42
```

I'm using 12.04 with all the latest updates.

nvidia-installer --version

nvidia-installer:  version 295.53  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-07.nvidia.com)  Sat May 12 00:34:26 PDT 2012
  The NVIDIA Software Installer for Unix/Linux.

This program is used to install, upgrade and uninstall The NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver Set for Linux-x86_64.

Copyright (C) 2003 - 2010 NVIDIA Corporation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by reinstalling my Nvidia driver.

If manually installed

```
telinit 3
```

then you need to switch to a tty prompt and login and type

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

then use your driver file and uninstall.

```
sudo sh ./driver_file.run --uninstall
```

If installed with package manager then just

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current
```

reboot and sudo apt-get install nvidia-current or just use the additional drivers icon inside your settings control panel.